# c++, converting input string to number, failure to convert should not return zero

Tags: c++, string, numbers, string-parsing

Hi im looking at the string conversion methods in c++  `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, `atol` etc. 
It seems  every single one of them will return a `0` (or `0.0`) as a result for a string that was impossible to convert. 
Assuming that `0` is a completely valid correct input for my  program how do I avoid converting nonsense strings to zero and make for example them throw some exception instead? Are there ready made functions that perform that way or do I have to wrap these with some of my own code.
Also could anybody explain me what might the reasons be that these functions are designed like this (Why build in the trouble of  separating nonsense string parse result from hones-to-god **"0"** string parse results)?

Answer (score 2):

Failure is indicated by setting `errno`, which is the old-fashioned C way of doing things.

You might find `stol` and friends more useful - they indicate failure by throwing an exception.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`std::stoi()` `std::stof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function family to do this. The functions will throw an exception for invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful [boost/lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html#boost_lexical_cast.examples.strings_to_numbers_conversion).